# OpenGL maximum FBOs and PBOs

Tags: opengl

Please tell me about some OpenGL 4.0 limitations:

1) What is the maximum of FBOs can i create?

2) What is the maximum of PBOs can i create?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The maximum depends on the amount of RAM + video RAM you have (and the complexity of each object). The graphic driver will determine the most efficient place to store the VBO/PBO, whether in your RAM or your video RAM.

Basically, you can create as much VBO/PBO as you wanted as long as you have any memory left.

Answer (score 2):

The [OpenGL specification](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec40.core.20100311.pdf) doesn't seem to dictate any specific value, so I believe that the memory is the only limit.

You'll know when you hit `glGetError() == GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY`.